# Is the equation $g_{\mu\nu} = const. + T_{\mu\nu}$ equivalent to Einstein's field equations?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Is the equation

$g_{\mu\nu} =$ diag (-1,1,1,1)$\cdot$ const. + $T_{\mu\nu}$

equivalent to Einstein's field equations?

$g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric tensor and  describes the curvature and $T_{\mu\nu}$ describes the stress-energy-momentum.

I guessed that from the fact that if $T = 0$, then $g = $ diag(-1,1,1,1) $\cdot$ const.

Comment: no (_space-filling text_).

Comment: Try making sense of this in terms of covariant derivatives, if not any mathematical points. $g_{\mu \nu }$ is the metric tensor, so I am not sure how it works here -- could you give some explanation as to the origin?

Comment: General relativity does not have “absolute” (i.e. non dynamical) tensors. So what is this $\mathrm{const.} $ that you use?

Comment: If it was, then why would everyone be using the insanely complicated Einstein equations instead of this simple and easy version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it simply fail to calculate correctly the gravitational field around a planet or star. The right side of the equation is zero in this case, but the space-time is not Minkowskian as your equation suggests.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the OP means $G_{\mu \nu}$ (the [Einstein tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor)) instead of $g_{\mu \nu}$ (which is the metric tensor). If that's the case then according to OP we should have

$$ G_{\mu \nu}=T_{\mu \nu} + {\rm const}$$
where
$$ G_{\mu \nu}=R_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} R $$
But we cannot really add a const term to a (0,2) tensor. However, what we can instead have is
$$ G_{\mu \nu}=T_{\mu \nu} + {\rm const} \, g_{\mu \nu}$$

where the constant term can bee seen as a term akin to [cosmological constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant).

Comment: I am not sure OP meant $G_{\mu \nu }$ instead of $g_{\mu \nu }$ -- if so, they clearly would have thought of expanding whatever that tensor was, and if they meant $G_{\mu \nu }$ they would have realised the equivalence with the field equations. Also, in pure GR, assuming by $T$ OP meant the trace of the stress tensor, if $T=0$, $G_{\mu \nu }$ must also vanish.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I did NOT mean G =T+const. I truely meant g = T + const. Yes, this constant has to be tensorial. I changed that to diag(-1,1,1,1) $\cdot$ const.

Comment: @Scibo And are you sure that means anything? For starters -- try looking at covariant derivatives, nature of the tensors, etc. The initial guess for the EFEs was $R_{\mu \nu }=T_{\mu \nu }$ (upto some factor). So, try seeing why $R_{\mu \nu }$ and not $g_{\mu \nu }$, this is a trivial thing. For starters, your assumption that $g=diag(-1, +1, +1, +1)$ in itself is wrong. This is the Minkowskian metric diagonal, which requires $T_{\mu \nu }=0$. Usually metric tensors do not have only diagonal terms.

Comment: Okay, thank you! That's important: why $R_{\mu\nu}$ and not $g_{\mu\nu} $? To be honest, I don't understand that difference.

Comment: @Scibo Try to ask and answer these questions: how does the metric encode curvature? What happens when $T_{\mu \nu }=0$? What happens with the covariant derivatives of both the sides? What does it mean to have Christoffel symbols $\Gamma ^{\alpha }_{\beta \gamma }$? Try deriving from the action. And so on. In short, neither $R_{\mu \nu }$ nor $g_{\mu \nu }$ are the correct curvature parts of the field equations. For that matter, it does not even make sense to have _only_ $g_{\mu \nu }$ as the curvature term.